# What does "Break into fours" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (2004)* movie, Students find Fat lady is missing from portraits:

> Keep calm, everyone. **Break into fours**. Back to your common room.

What does "Break into fours" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "split into groups of four people".